# Amazon SES - Using C# console app to send high quota of personalized emails per second

Tags: amazon-ses

Im using a C# console APP to send a personalized bulk email but I found the bottleneck that if I use sequential programming I'm only able to send 1 emails per second. I've tried to create a multi-thread app but I am able to send only two emails per second.

How can I do it better?

This is a fragment of the code:

public static void MainProgram(List emails ,string cuerpo_email_en, string cuerpo_email_es)
        {

```
       //emails list is populated with 50.000 emails

        DateTime timeControllerForSendingEmails = DateTime.Now;

        while (emails.Count > 0)
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - timeControllerForSendingEmails).TotalSeconds >= 1)
            {
                timeControllerForSendingEmails = DateTime.Now;

                //this method gets a list of 60 emails and remove them from the main list
                List<EmailEnt> queuedEmails = GetEmailsQueue(emails, 60));

                Send(queuedEmails);
            }

        }
    }

public void Send(List<EmailEnt> queuedEmails)
    {
        IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        List<string> logLines = new List<string>();

        foreach (EmailEnt emailEnt in queuedEmails)
        {
            string subject = "﻿Hello {name}";
            string body = "im the body;
            ﻿
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                SendEmail(emailEnt, subject, body);

            }));

        }


        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you are still running in 'sandbox mode'? According to AWS:

> When you are in the sandbox, your sending quota is 200 messages per
>   24-hour period and **your maximum sending rate is one message per
>   second.** To increase your sending limits, you need to request
>   production access. For more information, see Requesting Production
>   Access to Amazon SES. After you request production access and start
>   sending emails, you can increase your sending limits further by
>   following the guidance in the Increasing Your Amazon SES Sending
>   Limits section.

If not, I use code similar to this to send 15+ emails second (not on SES), and it works fine:

```
  Parallel.ForEach(mailQueue, new ParallelOptions() {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 7}, itm=>SendEmail(itm));
```

which perhaps is functionally equivalent to what you are doing already, but I can say for sure it does provide much greater throughput and may be worth a try.

Comment: The same wont work for Async methods, since the latest SES SDK 3 support only Async methods for .net core, Any example of that?